# Access member function from array of objects

Tags: c++

I'm trying to dynamically create an array of objects and then use the member functions of the objects in the array. I've tried a couple of combinations but crash my program when I try to invoke the display member on objects in the array.

```
Something * pSomethings[12] = { NULL }; //pointer to array of 12 Somethings

to load the array I use:
Something * pSomething; //create a temp pointer of Something
pSomething = pSomethings[0]; //assign temp pointer to first item in array
pSomething = new Widget(size, weight);//pSomthings[0] should be a new widget
cout << pSomething->getSize(); //seeing if data member was set (shows correct)
cout << pSomething->getWeight(); //seeing if data member was set (shows correct)

when I try to invoke the following my program breaks:
Something::display(){
Something * pSomething; //create another local temp pointer
pSomething = psomethings[0];//assign temp pointer to initialized pSomthing above
cout << pSomething->getSize(); // <---- breaks if run in main. 
}
```

I'm new to c++ and pointers in general so I could be making a very simple mistake but I simply don't understand why getSize() displays correctly in the first function but in display() I create everything the same (temp pointer, assign to same index etc.) and I get an error.

Comment: That's actually an array of 12 pointers to Something and not *pointer to array of 12 Somethings*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the comments here:

```
pSomething = pSomethings[0]; //assign temp pointer to first item in array
pSomething = new Widget(size, weight);//pSomthings[0] should be a new widget
```

The last comment is incorrect as you assign the value returned by `new` to `pSomething`, *not* to `pSomethings[0]`.

You should have written:

```
pSomethings[0] = new Widget(size, weight); //pSomthings[0] should be a new widget
```

Now the code *and* the comment are correct.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! I didn't know I could use pSomethings[0] with index notation and still use pointer resolution ->. How would I assign on of the psomething[index] index's to another temp pointer?

Comment: @user2093601, `auto ptr = pSomethings[index]`?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing things in the wrong order.

You're also thinking a bit backwards about assignment – `x = a` reads "assign a to x", not the other way around.

In particular, in the sequence

```
pSomething = pSomethings[0]; //assign temp pointer to first item in array
pSomething = new Widget(size, weight);//pSomthings[0] should be a new widget
```

the first assignment assigns the array's first element to `pSomething`, and the second assignment has no effect on the array – it's still a null pointer.
There's nothing special about pointers; that code works exactly like

```
int x;
int y = 2;
x = y;
x = 10;
```

and you would expect `y` to be `2` and not `10` after that, right?

Rearranging your code and making the code match your comments would make it valid:

```
Something * pSomethings[12] = { NULL }; //pointer to array of 12 Somethings

pSomethings[0] = new Widget(size, weight);//pSomethings[0] should be a new widget
Something * pSomething; //create a temp pointer to Something
pSomething = pSomethings[0]; //assign first item in array to temp pointer
```